# Python - simple list function giving name error

Tags: python

Fairly simple question, I imagine...I have literally just installed Python and am testing some of the beginner tutorials.

I wanted to create a menu that allows you to add items to a list, then check to see if theyre added: testing functions, and lists in the process.

```
#create empty list and define variables
firstlist = {'joe'}
additem = "test"
printthis = "test"

#create menu, add or check name
def menu():
    #print what options you have
    print "Add to list: type '1'"
    print "Check for name: type '2'"
    print "To exit program: type '3'"
    return input ("Choose your option: ")

def addmenu():
    additem = input("Name of list item: ")
    firstlist.append(additem)
    print additem, "has been appended"

def checkmenu():
    printthis = input ("What are you looking for?: ")
    if firstlist.has_key(printthis):
        print "is in the list"
    else:
        print "is not in the list"

# Perform action
loop = 1
choice = 0
while loop == 1:
    choice = menu()
    if choice == 1:
        addmenu()
    elif choice == 2:
        checkmenu()
    elif choice == 3:
        loop = 0
    elif choice > 3:
        print "You made an incorrect selection"
```

Heres my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\testing python\tutorials\dictionaryselection", line 32, in <module>
    addmenu()
  File "C:\Python27\testing python\tutorials\dictionaryselection", line 15, in addmenu
    additem = input("Name of list item: ")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'TESTING' is not defined
```

Not sure whats going on...Any help would be appreciated.

Working code below: converted to python 3.x

```
#create empty list and define variables
firstlist = ['Joe']
additem = "test"
printthis = "test"

#create menu, add or check name
def menu():
    #print what options you have
    print ("")
    print ("Add to list: type '1'")
    print ("Check for name: type '2'")
    print ("To list the whole list '3'")
    print ("To exit program: type '4'")
    print ("-------------------------")
    return input ("Choose your option: ")

def addmenu():
    additem = input("Name of list item: ")
    firstlist.append(additem)
    print (additem, "has been appended")

def checkmenu():
    printthis = input("What are you looking for?: ")
    if printthis in firstlist:
        print ("is in the list")
    else:
        print ("is not in the list")

def listlist():
    print (firstlist[1])

# Perform action
loop = 1
choice = 0
while loop == 1:
    choice = int(menu())
    if choice == 1:
        addmenu()
    elif choice == 2:
        checkmenu()
    elif choice == 3:
        listlist()
    elif choice == 4:
        loop = 0
    elif (choice > 4):
        print ("You made an incoorect selection")
```

Comment: Where did you get this example from ? It is wrong in multiple ways. `firstlist` could be a set or a list, but the definition would be wrong for the later and doesn't match the name. Given the formatting of `print` statements, you are using Python 2, thus you must generally use raw_input instead of input and convert the result as appropriated. `input()` is the same as `eval(raw_input())`, and that is the reason you get such an error.

Comment: i made the code up based on other examples.  just helps me figure out how it works.  I dont know what a `set` is...haven't gotten there yet!  I believe I am using python 2.  `eval(raw_input())` did not seem to get rid of the error.

Comment: @RickyMason He wasn't saying you should use `eval(raw_input())`, he was saying that's the equivalent of what you are already doing. Just use `raw_input()` since you're using Python 2.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple errors in the example, let us go through them. First, if you want a list then you need to define it as such, i.e.:

```
l = ['joe'] # this is a list
s = {'joe'} # this is a set
```

Now, since you are using Python 2, it is always recommended to use `raw_input` in place of `input`. The later will apply `eval` on the obtained string, so it will evaluate the input as Python code. You generally don't want that for security reasons (I know this is an example). So, let's change every `input` to `raw_input`. The problem now is that entering a string that represents a number while using `eval`, actually converts the string to a number. Now you need to do the same, but using `raw_input`. Since your options are limited to integer values, the solution is `int(raw_input())`.

The third problem is related to `has_key`. If the object used is a `set` or a `list`, then there is no such method `has_key` defined for them. That would work if the object in question were a `dict`, but it is not. The proper way to check for containment in the given code is `something in A`. Doing this while using `set` is much more efficient than while using `list`, and the code remains the same (except you need to change `append` to `add`).

Can you adjust your code now ?

Comment: thank you. your earlier comment finally hit me as I was looking through the original tutorial.  This helped a lot.

Comment: That is nice, Python's tutorial and its documentation in general is a good place to go.

Answer (score 1):

With firstlist, you're mixing the idea of a list and the idea of a dictionary.  It looks like you just want a list ...

```
firstlist = ['Joe']
```

also, instead of using has_key, write

```
if printthis in firstlist:
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#create empty list and define variables
firstlist = {}
additem = ""
printthis = ""
removeitem = ""
#create menu, add, remove or check name
def menu():
    print "Add to list: type '1'"
    print "Remove from the list: type '2'"
    print "Check for name: type '3'"
    print "To exit program: type '4'"
    return input("Choose your option: ")
def addmenu():
    additem = raw_input("Name of list item: ")
    firstlist[additem] = additem
    print additem, "has been appended"
def removemenu():
    removeitem = raw_input("Name of list item: ")
    firstlist.pop(removeitem)
    print removeitem, " has been removed"
def checkmenu():
    printthis = raw_input("What are you looking for?: ")
    if firstlist.has_key(printthis):
        print printthis, " is in the list"
    else:
        print printthis, " is not in the list"

# Perform action
loop = 1
choice = 0
while loop == 1:
    choice = menu()
    if choice == 1:
        addmenu()
    elif choice == 2:
        removemenu()
    elif choice == 3:
        checkmenu()
    elif choice == 4:
        loop = 0
    elif choice > 4:
        print "You made an incorrect selection"
```

Answer (score 0):

## @ Ricky Mason : I have  modified the code a bit. Here you would need a dict object and not a set or a list. A dict object #since has a key value pair would be easy to retrieve the values that you are looking for in the checkmenu and at the same #time you can remove the values from the list too. I hope this helps. Feel free to post any further queries regarding the same.

Here is the code in following reply